# expressjs: How to catch all route parameters even if unknown?

Tags: express, routes

Lets say I have this route.

```
this.app.use('/app/fileasset/ui.html/:view*?', function(req,res) {});
```

If I have this url: /app/fileasset/ui.html **/test/view**

Then I can catch them in req.params ==> req.params[0] (root url, 'test') and req.params.view ('view')

The question is: how can I catch an unknown numbers of parameters ?

For example: /app/fileasset/ui.html **/test/view/subview/wtv**

How to get 'subview' and 'wtv' in req.params ? and having the same route to catch longer url with unknown number of params ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpressJS routing does allow to use wildcards, if you do something like this:

```
this.app.use('/app/fileasset/ui.html/*', function(req,res) {});
```

Then going to a url like `/app/fileasset/ui.html/test/view/subview/wtv` should populate req.params with `"['test/view/subview/wtv']"` which you can easily split on the forward slash.

Answer (score -1):

Do you tryed foreach over req.params?

```
req.params.forEach(function (item) {
  someFn(item);
})
```

or just for

```
for (var i = 0, len = req.params.length; i < len; i++) {
  someFn(req.params[i]);
}
```